# DataGridView comboBox with different dataSources for each cell vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox, datasource

How can i make a datagridview combobox with different datasource for each row?
I'm using VB.net 2010 and MYSQL database. the datasource which will be added to comboboxes are from database.
 
goal:

```
    code               condition          comboboxoption
    ID1                  A                  {B}{C}{D}
    ID2                  1                  {1}{2}{3}
    ID3                  A                  {B}{C}{D}
    ID4                  A1                 {1}{C}{D}
```

just simple logic. if condition [in column condition] is A then combobox datasource are B,C and D [select from database]. if condition is 1 then 1,2,3, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Show what you have tried please.

Comment: This has been answered in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162744/datagridview-combobox-with-different-datasources-for-each-cell